# how does phantomjs onResourceRequested calculate referer

Tags: phantomjs

I set resource requests log in my js

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  console.log('Request (#' + requestData.id + '): ' +     JSON.stringify(requestData));
};
```

run the script

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 /tmp/jsFjaBPz
```

getting a lot requests log like

```
Request (#8): {"headers":[{"name":"Accept","value":"*/*"},{"name":"Referer","value":"http://ihidemydomain.com/pdf/?id=9375401"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1"}],"id":8,"method":"GET","time":"2016-02-26T18:10:00.070Z","url":"https://ihidemydomain.com/assets/bower_components/typed.js/js/typed.js"}
```

What is strange it somehow set `Referer` to `http://ihidemydomain.com/pdf/?id=9375401` and then all ajax request in `typed.js` go under http instead of https.